# Should node servers listen on HTTPS only or both HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ssl, https

So I just finished setting up HTTPS for my website and got that all working so when I go to mywebsite.com it says the page is secure and automatically connects over HTTPS.

My question is: is there even a point to having the node server listen for HTTP traffic as well? I guess what I'm unsure about is what percent of user clients' browsers support https or if there is any reason to allow http traffic.

My app requires native websockets as well (requires >2011 browsers) so I'd imagine that all browsers past that would support https. Are there any instances or situations where clients can't use https and have to connect over http? Perhaps some mobile devices?

What are the pros and cons towards listening for only https as opposed to opening up both port 80 and 443?

Comment: *"My app requires native websockets as well (requires >2011 browsers) so I'd imagine that all browsers past that would support https."* Er, yeah -- and for more than 15 years before that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: So is there any point to listen on port 80? Should I just have the server only listen on port 443?

Comment: You should listen on port 80 to redirect it to https.

Comment: @Matt: But when I type in `mywebsite.com` it automatically goes to the https version. Under what circumstances would a node express redirect be necessary?

Comment: @ChronBag Maybe your client tries https or remembers https? Not all clients are that smart.

Comment: @Matt: Ah yes you're right it was remembering. Ok I'll redirect.